# Identify in-text Citations (in APA, MLA, Harvard, Vancouver, etc.) with Python

Tags: python, citations

I'm trying to identify all sentences that contain in-text citations in a journal article in pdf  formats.
I converted the .pdf to .txt and wanted to find all sentences that contained a citation, possibly in one of the following format:

1. Smith (1990) stated that....
2. An agreement was made on... (Smith, 1990).
3. An agreement was made on... (April, 2005; Smith, 1990)
4. Mixtures of the above

I first tokenized the txt into sentences:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
ss = sent_tokenize(text)
```

[image]
This makes type(ss) list, so I converted the list into str to use re findall:

```
def listtostring(s):
    str1 = ' '
    return (str1. join(s))
ee = listtostring(ss)
```

Then, my idea was to identify the sentences that contained a four digit number:

```
import re
for sentence in ee:
    zz = re.findall(r'\d{4}', ee)
    if zz:
        print (zz)
```

However, this extracts only the years but not the sentences that contained the years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for recognizing in-text citations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320958/regular-expression-for-recognizing-in-text-citations)

Answer (score 2):

Using regex, something ([try it out](https://regex101.com/r/psydOY/1/)) that can have decent recall while trying to avoid inappropriate matches (`\d{4}` may give you a few) is

```
\(([^)]+)?(?:19|20)\d{2}?([^)]+)?\)
```

A python example (using spaCy instead of NLTK) would then be

```
import re
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

doc = nlp("One statement. Then according to (Smith, 1990) everything will be all right. Or maybe not.")

l = [sent.text for sent in doc.sents]

for sentence in l:
    if re.findall(r'\(([^)]+)?(?:19|20)\d{2}?([^)]+)?\)', sentence):
        print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
l = ['This is 1234','Hello','Also 1234']

for sentence in l:
    if re.findall(r'\d{4}',sentence):
        print(sentence)
```

Output

```
This is 1234
Also 1234
```