# Python regex to get citations in a paper

Tags: python, regex, text, citations

I was adapting [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826935) for extracting citations from a text:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826935

import re
from sys import stdin

text = stdin.read()

author = "(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z'`-]+)"
etal = "(?:et al.?)"
additional = "(?:,? (?:(?:and |& )?" + author + "|" + etal + "))"
year_num = "(?:19|20)[0-9][0-9]"
page_num = "(?:, p.? [0-9]+)?"  # Always optional
year = "(?:, *"+year_num+page_num+"| *\("+year_num+page_num+"\))"
regex = "(" + author + additional+"*" + year + ")"

matches = re.findall(regex, text)
matches = list( dict.fromkeys(matches) )
matches.sort()

#print(matches)
print ("\n".join(matches))
```

However, it recognizes some uppercased words as author names. For example, in the text:

```
Although James (2020) recognized blablabla, Smith et al. (2020) found mimimi. 
Those inconsistent results are a sign of lalala (Green, 2010; Grimm, 1990). 
Also James (2020) ...
```

The output would be

```
Also James (2020)
Although James (2020)
Green, 2010
Grimm, 1990
Smith et al. (2020)
```

Is there a way to "blacklist" some words in the above code without removing the entire match? I wish it recognized James' work but removed "Also" and "Although" from the citation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
author = r"(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z'`-]+)"
etal = r"(?:et al\.?)"
additional = f"(?:,? (?:(?:and |& )?{author}|{etal}))"
year_num = "(?:19|20)[0-9][0-9]"
page_num = "(?:, p\.? [0-9]+)?"  # Always optional
year = fr"(?:, *{year_num}{page_num}| *\({year_num}{page_num}\))"
regex = fr'\b(?!(?:Although|Also)\b){author}{additional}*{year}'
matches = re.findall(regex, text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IqZvxm) and the [resulting regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xssPEs/1).

The main difference is at `regex = fr'\b(?!(?:Although|Also)\b){author}{additional}*{year}'`, the `\b(?!(?:Although|Also)\b)` part will fail if the word that is immediately on the right is `Although` or `Also`.

Also, note I escaped dots that are supposed to match literal dots, and use the f-strings to make the code look a bit more compact.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any possibility to also remove the page number in the end? They count twice when in fact they all cite the same document.

Comment: @IuriGavronski I do not know what exact output you would like to get. Try https://regex101.com/r/xssPEs/2

Comment: I find the two websites you pointed to (regex101 and ideone) awesome. Thanks! I believe you nailed it. In fact, my best-case scenario would be outputting all references in a standard format, such as James (2020), so the list(dict()) thing would remove duplicate entries. My end game is comparing the list of references at the end of an academic paper with the citations in the text. This is a very time-consuming process, and this script is going a long way in shortening that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, the previous answer did not work for some citations.

```
regexr.com/6er6n
```

This answer I got from other source, but it did not work for one other type of citation text. My version fixes that:

```
citationsRegex = r"\b(?!(?:Although|Also)\b)(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z'`-]+)(?:,? (?:(?:and |& )?(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z'`-]+)|(?:et al.?)))*(?:,? *(?:19|20)[0-9][0-9](?:, p\.? [0-9]+)?| *\((?:19|20)[0-9][0-9](?:, p\.? [0-9]+)?\))"
```

Comment: Could you explain why your regex pattern doesn't correctly extract *some citations*?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The only difference with my solution is that one `,?` (in ``(?:et al.?)))*(?:,?``) is replaced with `,`, so all you suggest is to make a comma obligatory.

Comment: Instead of just a comma, we could write `,+` .